# TYPO3 domain and subdomain with one installation

Tags: content-management-system, typo3

Have following problem.

I use TYPO3 version 4.7.1 and for both sites the domain record is configured.

- Internet site → `www.domain.com` → root id = `77`
- Extranet site → `service.domain.com` → root id = `104`

But still, both sites will be redirect to the internet site.

How must I set this up?

Comment: Please note that nested domains records are not supported. Make sure to move each domain page tree to the top.

Answer (score 1):

Did you create a template for each domain? Did you set those templates as root?

See http://wiki.typo3.org/Multidomain for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Also go to the page properties/edit -> behaviour -> Miscellaneous -> Use as root: check the checkbox.

Clear caches.

If possible  set the following:

```
[globalString = ENV:HTTP_HOST=domain.local]
config.baseURL = http://domain.local
[globalString = ENV:HTTP_HOST=www.domain1.tld]
config.baseURL = http://www.domain1.tld
[globalString = ENV:HTTP_HOST=www.domain2.tld]
config.baseURL = http://www.domain2.tld
[global]
```