# TYPO3 multidomain

Tags: cross-domain, typo3, typoscript

I've got a question about more domains in TYPO3.

I'd like to build a tree which has 2 domains.

If I load the first url, I would like to load the first site,

If I load the second url, I would like to load the second site.

The domains are stored in each site.

Is it possible to do this without using the `.htaccess` file ?

Does somebody has a tutorial or help for me ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [TYPO3 domain and subdomain with one installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235796/typo3-domain-and-subdomain-with-one-installation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at http://wiki.typo3.org/Multidomain

No, you don't need special `.htaccess` directives.

Answer (score 4):

1) Create page and make it as a root page.

2) Add domain for your root page.

3) Edit domain and give path of your site to domain.

And there is no need to do anything in .htaccess

Answer (score 3):

It's very easy to handle multiple domains using typo3.
3 steps:

1. Add the site address to DNS.
2. In typo3 backend, create a "domain record" at the root page of the site "aaa" as aaa.com and another domain record at the root page of the site "bbb" as bbb.com.
3. Update the domain root page templates with the below typoscript:

   config.baseURL = aaa.com # in the first domain's root ts template

   config.baseURL = bbb.com # in the second domain's root ts template

Note: You can also add one more domain record in each domain's root page for redirecting to 
www.aaa.com and www.bbb.com using the domain record options.

Answer (score 2):

Just point another vhost/alias to this directory. Domain records handles it all.
Don't forget to check realurl config - sometimes there's need to configure it's settings in different way to every domain.
Important - if you share records between domains (eg. tt_news) you have to make identical config for it's postVarSets for each domain. If not, realurl will generate links as ugly hashes.